# How high is a tab bar in iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I tried to get that info, but google returns me just nothing about that. Does anyone know that exactly? I remember a value around 40 units, but I am not sure. The Constants.h of UICatalog.xcodeproj doesn't mention it.

Comment: [Here](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html) is a useful link with dimensions of different UI elements.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you mean the height then it is **49 px**.

To find this I went into Interface Builder, created a blank view, then set Simulated Metrics -> Bottom Bar -> Tab Bar and noted the new dimensions of the view (320x431).

480 - 431 = 49px

Answer (score 1):

You can also drop a

```
    NSLog(@"Tab Bar dimensions : %@", NSStringFromCGRect(yourTabBarController.tabBar.frame));
```

To see a string containing {{x, y}, {width, height}} wherever you alloc'ed the UITabBarController. You'll get 49 though, maybe this is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me, and don't like hardcoding these things, try:

```
UITabBarController *tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarHeight = tabBar.tabBar.frame.size.height;
```

I put the first line in a utilities class (which is initialized at app startup), and just access tabBarHeight after that.